# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.19f83932.js:1:1) main.19f83932.js:1

Tags: reactjs

I installed my first React Application on a VPS server.
When I try to access a page directly with

http:xx.xxx.xxx.xx/post/22

I only get a blank page with the error in the console:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.19f83932.js:1:1) main.19f83932.js:1

If the page is accessed via a link from the main overview, the page i am looking for is displayed correctly.

This behavior only happens on the VPS server.

If I try the same thing on my development computer, e.g. with http://localhost:3000/post/22
the page is also displayed correctly.

Here the index.html from folder public:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
   <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
   <meta name="description"content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
   <link 
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2family=Josefin+Sans:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700&family=Lora:ital,wght@1,400;1,500;1,600&family=Varela&family=Varela+Round&display=swap" 
  rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" 
  integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" 
  crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <style>*{
    margin: 0;
  }
  </style>
  <style>
    .link{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: inherit;
    }
  </style>
<title>A Blog</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
   <div id="root"></div>
 </body>
```

The entire project is uploaded to github:
https://github.com/MailiEder/upgraded-dollop

Would be very grateful for a helpful hint.

Thank you Lars for your feedback.

I installed an API- and a client side on the VPS via github. A build of the client (npm run build) was created.
I use nginx. The project is just a small exercise: register, log in, create posts. Everything works wonderfully,
except for this error:

After creating a new post, it should be displayed with:

window.location.replace("/post/" + res.data.postid)

However, only a blank page is displayed, with the error mentioned above.
For example, the browser says http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/post/18.

If you open the most recently created post via the main page, the browser now says
again http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/post/18, the page is displayed.

Comment: Do you plan to only run a frontend on this VPS? If so the recommended way to publish your project is to run `npm run build` and upload the contents of the `dist` or `build` folder to a web server running on your VPS something like `nginx` or `apache`